# Why does `K.cast` is used in `categorical_accuracy`, instead of `K.mean`?

Tags: python, keras

The function `keras.metrics.binary_accuracy` is very straightforward:

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L20

However the function `keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy` has something different:

```
def categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.cast(K.equal(K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1),
                          K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)),
                  K.floatx())
```

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/metrics.py#L24

I am very confused that why this function uses `K.cast`, instead of `K.mean`? Because I think that this function should return a number just like the function `keras.metrics.binary_accuracy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for `cast` is because `argmax` returns an integer, It's the index of the highest value. But the result must be a float.

**The `argmax` function:**

The `argmax` function will also reduce the rank of the inputs. Notice it uses `axis=-1`, meaning it will take the index of the maximum value in the last axis, eliminating that axis, but keeping the other axes.

Supposing  your input had shape `(10 samples, 5 features)`, the returned tensor would be just `(10 samples,)`

**The `mean` function with `axis=-1`:**

Normally, the `mean` function returns a scalar, but if you look closely at `binary_accuracy`, you will also notice that, by using `axis=-1` in the `mean` function, it doesn't reduce the input to a single scalar value. It reduces the tensor exactly the same way `argmax` does, but in this case, calculating a mean value.

An input `(10,5)` would come out also as `(10,)`.

**Final result:**

So, we can conclude that both metrics return tensors with the same shape. Now, the reason they both don't reduce everthing to a scalar value is because Keras offers more possibilities, such as sample weighting and a few other additional operations with the loss (including your own custom losses if you want to take Keras' as a base). These will rely on having the loss separed by samples.

Later somewhere, Keras will calculate the final mean.